# Logging a literal message in NLog and/or Serilog

Tags: .net, formatting, escaping, nlog, serilog

UPDATE: This turned out to be a discrepancy that exists in Serilog (which I tunnel to), but does *not* exist in NLog, which treats a single argument as a verbatim string (as one (and specifically, I) might expect)

---

Using NLog, if I want to log something potentially containing embedded double braces: `{{` without having them collapsed, what's the most efficient way?

e.g.:

```
NLog.LogManager.GetLogger("x").Warn("{{\"aaa}}")
```

emits in my custom serilog-target:

```
{"aaa}
```

And I want:

```
{{"aaa}}
```

Is

```
NLog.LogManager.GetLogger("x").Warn("{0}","{{\"aaa}}")
```

the best way or is there a more efficient way ?

UPDATE: no such tricks required:

```
NLog.LogManager.GetLogger("x").Warn("{{\"aaa}}")
```

... does indeed just work!

(This is not (just) me being pedantic, its a follow-on from [a question regarding a high perf/throughput requirement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49592351/redirect-all-nlog-output-to-serilog-with-a-custom-target]))

Comment: Not sure I understand. NLog doesn't do any parsing of the string if not providing any parameters. So your first example doesn't make sense, unless you have a broken target.

Comment: @RolfKristensen Yes, 100% correct (see my declaration below). It does mean the answer in the linked question by Julian turns out to be wrong though:- the forwarder needs to materialize using NLog's formatting

Comment: I guess your work-around will do then, though I would probably do it in the custom target. If no parameters then inject the string as parameter to Serilog using the message template `{0}` (Serilog caches message templates so it should be inexpensive)

Comment: Guess you should rephrase your question to "Logging a literal message in Serilog" :)

Comment: @RolfKristensen LOL. I met you half way on the title ;) (And had already done the transition in the obvious place:- the `SerilogTarget`). Thanks for the thinking, checking and validation.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the question is wrong. The code above works in NLog - a single string is not treated as a message template and *is* rendered verbatim.

I was tunneling it thru to Serilog per the linked question, and Serilog was doing the collapsing I show the effects of in the question.