# Trying to use NLog and Serilog Together

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, nlog, serilog

I'm trying to use NLog and Serilog together but NLog won't work when I add the:

```xml
<PackageReference Include="Serilog" Version="3.0.1" />
```

in my csproj file, so basically when I add them together only Serilog works but to get NLog working I need to remove Serilog.

Comment: Pick one. Why would you need to use both at the same time?

Comment: We're trying to move to serilog but we need nlog temporarily because converting the nlog configurations to serilog configurations would be too much work

Comment: How much configuration do you have? Also: what do you mean by "too much work"? If it's an "all-or-nothing" task, that's what branches are for.

Comment: what is the Nlog and .net core version?try using the logging bridge, Serilog has a package called `Serilog.Sinks.NLog` which allows you to direct Serilog log events into NLog. could you please share some sample code how you are using both in your project? If you're migrating from NLog to Serilog, do it incrementally. Start by replacing NLog in less critical parts of your application and gradually move to more critical parts as you resolve issues.as a workaround try initializing NLog before Serilog or vice versa

Comment: You need to pick one writer and redirect the other tho that. To redirect NLog to Serilog: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49639001/11635

Comment: Whereas there may be reasonable work-arounds, and whereas I won't actually be adding anything of value, I feel it should be said that this thread is an indication that Serilog is fundamentally badly architected (doesn't play well with others).  "Pick one" is understandable, but actually a bad answer.  We should be able to add as many loggers as we like, and they should all work independently.  For example, you can AddDebug and AddConsole today and both work - one doesn't replace the other.